# What provides energy in mutual inductance to unconnected coil

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, energy-conservation, inductance, lenz-law

In this mutual inductance setup:

[image]

when current is passed through coil 1 the flux through coil 2 changes for a short amount of time which induces a current in coil 2 the direction of which, in accordance with Lenz's law, is opposite to that of current in coil 1. My question is, what provides the energy to current in coil 2 since it is not connected to any power source. The only possibility I can think of is that this energy is provided by the magnetic field caused by coil 1, but then the magnitude of magnetic field must *decrease* to keep total energy of system constant since the energy stored in a field at that point depends on the strength (magnitude) of the field at that point, and this may also be supported by the fact that the current in coil 2 induces a magnetic field opposite in direction to the original magnetic field, so that it's magnitude does decrease. But I cannot find an analogous case in an electric field because when a particle's kinetic energy increase due to electric field, we simply say that the particle's potential energy at that point converts into it's kinetic energy, but the magnitude of the electric field remains constant, so why must the magnitude of magnetic field decrease in this case? What am I missing, thanks.

Comment: It happens in electric fields too. There are substances called dielectrics which when placed in a electric field, oppose the direction of electric field. As a result, Electric field inside the dielectric is less than the applied electric field. You can think of it as electric field using energy to polarise the dielectric and hence the magnitude of electric field decreases inside the dielectric.

Answer (score 1):

When a test particle is accelerated inside an electric field, it is supposed by hypothesis to be small enough to not affect the field. But to be precise, it is really a (small) changing current that produces a changing magnetic field around. That changing magnetic field induces an electric field that tends to decrease the initial one.